# Adjusting volume levels with ffmpeg afade

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am having some trouble with the following ffmpeg command string:

`ffmpeg -i 20s.wav -af "afade=t=out:st=2:d=1:silence=0.07, afade=t=in:st=5:d=1" out.wav`

What I expect from this: At 2 seconds, fade the volume to 0.07 over the course of 1 seconds duration. Then at 5 seconds duration, fade the volume back to unity (default value 1.0) over 1 seconds duration.

Instead, the result begins with a volume level of 0.0. Then at 5 seconds it fades up to 0.07 to remain for the duration of the file.

Any thoughts on how to achieve what I am looking for? Thanks!

Comment: trim audio, afade then concat: `ffmpeg -t 5 -i input.mp3 -ss 5 -i input.mp3 -lavfi "
[0]afade=t=out:st=2:d=1:silence=0.07[a];
[1]afade=t=in:d=1:silence=0.07[b];
[a][b]concat=2:0:1
" out.wav`

Comment: Excellent! Yes this works! Thank you!